# copy data from one table to another with different primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have to migrate data in sqlserver from one table to another. Most of the standalone table were possible with select and insert into sp's.

The issue is in one table from the old database there is a column with a primary key say unit.

Now this unit is divided into two parts in the new database for example 'industry' and 'resource'.i.e industry + resource together constitute the unit.

How can i go about with the migration of this.

Comment: what is the distinction between the two parts? Is there a "category" column or similar?

Comment: What is the datatype of unit and the two parts in both the databses, if its a varchar do you have a delimeter

Comment: Anukit, we can help you more if you post your CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: The create table statement for new table

CREATE TABLE [tbl1](
 [IndustryID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ResID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [Type] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
 
 
) ON [PRIMARY]

The old table:
CREATE TABLE [Unit](
 [UnitID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 [Type] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
 
 
 
) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar "Database Transformation" tasks with [SQL Server Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/integration-services.aspx) it does require that you have SQL Server Standard or Enterprise (not Express) but because it is part of SQL Server there is no additional licencing, if it isn't installed you may need to re-run the installer and select "Integration Services".

SSIS will allow you to create a data flow, aranging the data more or less how you want it. There are several [tutorials on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx).